# No metadata for user was found

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am new to nodejs using nestjs framework.
My dbConfig.ts:

```html
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { UsersEntity } from "../entity/users.entity";
dotenv.config();

export const dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  entities: ['dist/entity/*.entity.js'],
  migrations: ['dist/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
};
console.log(__dirname + '/**/*.entity.{js,ts}');
const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);
export default dataSource;
```

My dist folder structure is like
dist
-entity
--users.entity.d.ts
--users.entity.js

Answer (score 0):

try to set entites,migrations like :

```
import { UsersEntity } from "../entity/users.entity";

import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const ENTITIES=[UsersEntity]
const MIGRATIONS=[migration...<timestamp related number>]

export const dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  entities: ENTITIES,
  migrations: MIGRATIONS,
};

const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);
export default dataSource;
```

it should work